# How come my desktop computer is still on kernel 3.13.0-63-generic, when current version is 3.13.0-70?

Tags: kernel, updates

It used to update nicely, until 63.

I have other computers on Lubuntu and Xubuntu, and they are both still updating correctly.

Comment: I ask this question because I saw that the headers are updating to version 70 today on this computer, so I ran `uname-a` to check where it was at currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try updating the kernels that have been downloaded then update your `grub` file.

When I checked the `apt-cache` for the kernel, it returned the following:

```
apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.13.0-70-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-70-generic:
  Installed: 3.13.0-70.113
  Candidate: 3.13.0-70.113
  Version table:
 *** 3.13.0-70.113 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

from what I can see the kernel files come from `trusty-updates main` and `trusty-security main`.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure that the following lines are not commented `#` out or make sure that they exist:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
```

Run the following to make sure the newest kernel is downloaded:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Also from our conversation, install the generic kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

If it installs the kernel correctly, there would be no reason to go any further than here.

---

To update the current installed kernels, from a terminal prompt type in:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

You should see something like:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-70-generic
```

Then type in the following to update `grub`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If the kernel was installed correctly, you should see something similar to the following:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-70-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sdd1
done
```

Once you have seen

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-70-generic
```

reboot your system so it will boot to the `3.13.0-70-generic` kernel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that @Terrance.

That's the mysterious part, though. Only the headers seem to update, and the kernels stopped updating. For example, from just then:

`el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-58-generic

...etc
`

Comment: @el_gallo_azul It looks like it didn't download the whole thing then.  Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  I am going to add that to my answer as well.

Comment: That didn't nail it either:

`el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmm-glib0 modemmanager
2 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 603 kB of archives.
After this operation, 103 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(truncated here for space in askubuntu.com comment field)`

Comment: Why would it have stopped getting the new kernels a while ago?

Comment: @el_gallo_azul I updated my answer again to check for missing repositories or uncomment the required lines for the kernel updates.

Comment: I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I was using my ISP's mirror repository, but I changed it to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted` and `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted` just in case there was a problem with the mirror. It didn't make any difference.

Comment: @el_gallo_azul Hmmmm, you are running the `sudo apt-get update` after these changes to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, right?  Also, make sure your list matches the other lists from your other two installations that work correctly.  Usually updates like this stop because the repositories that are supposed to cover the applications get removed or stop working.  Did you notice any errors when you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: There are some errors right at the end, but they've been there for years  - since well before kernel `3.13.0-63`.

`N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: Unknown error executing gpgv` (cont...)

Comment: ...`W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_plexmediaserver_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_plexmediaserver_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)
`...

Comment: ...`W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_archive_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.vivaldi.com_archive_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)`

Comment: @el_gallo_azul Yeah, those don't have anything to do with the kernel, but I recommend cleaning them up that are no longer working.  Have you tried installing the generic LTS kernel `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty` ?

Comment: Thanks. I did `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty` and now I am running on 3.13.0-70-generic.  I hope I don't have to do that every time I see the headers are updated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @el_gallo_azul  You shouldn't have to.  I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.  That is one of the steps for the Hardware Enablement Stack for LTS releases, and you don't add new repos, but your system detects the change and updates in the future.  Anyway, glad you got it fixed!  =)